# Change Enter event behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am try to apply placeholder on p and div tag.using following code

HTML

```
 <div id="test" placeholder="Start writing here..."></div>
```

CSS

```
 #test:empty:after {
    content: attr(placeholder);
 }
```

Now in edit mode when i write something in that div tag and then press "enter" at that time it will create same div tag with attribute in chrome (so in place of space it print "start writing here.." ,bcz same tag created), in firefox it only create "br" tag instead of same tag.
So what is solution of that and using that it not create same tag agian and it create only br tag.

Comment: Not really clear how to recreate your problem. How and where do you edit the div?

Comment: I am working on cms and in website editor i want to put the one placeholder like above ,but it create problem on eneter event.

Comment: i want like : http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/#rich2 . Its feature of Medium.com

Answer (score 0):

So if I get you right, you want an area (your `<div id="test" ...>`) where you can enter text. Then you want a *placeholder* string (`Start writing here...`) for this area. What do you want to do with the entered text? I guess sooner or later you want to send the *text* to a server!? So what about a `form` element and a

```
<textarea placeholder="Start writing here..."></textarea>
```

[Here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-textarea-element) you have the w3c spec. Using standard HTML elements will provide you with a lot of benefits, form accessibility to usability, from browser support to performance.

Comment: hello,i m good with div tag,bug when i press enter at that time it will create same tag in which i press enter using google chrome. and in firefox it will create br tag , so how to change this chrome behaviour as like firefox??